# how to insert error returned from copy command from .bat file into table

Tags: postgresql, batch-file, export-to-csv, postgresql-9.5

[batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file):

```
cd C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v5\runtime
psql -h "Hostname" -p "5432" -U "user_name" -d "dbname" -c "\COPY (SELECT * FROM schema_name.table_name) TO "C:\ExportFromStaging\outputfile.csv" WITH (FORMAT CSV, HEADER TRUE, FORCE_QUOTE *, QUOTE '\"', ESCAPE '''',DELIMITER ';')
```

Expectation :

If any error occurs in `copy` command, I want to catch error rerturned from Database eighter in local variable or in table

Example batch file:

````
cd C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v5\runtime
psql -h "Hostname" -p "5432" -U "user_name" -d "dbname" -c "\COPY (SELECT * FROM schema_name.table_name) TO "C:\ExportFromStaging\outputfile.csv" WITH (FORMAT CSV, HEADER TRUE, FORCE_QUOTE *, QUOTE '\"', ESCAPE '''',DELIMITER ';')


if error 
then 
insert into error_log (error_message,error_time)
values (@ERRROR_RETURNED_FROM_DATABASE_IFCOPPYING_WENT_WRONG,timestamp);

echo @ERRROR_RETURNED_FROM_DATABASE_IF_COPPYING_WENT_WRONG
```
````

Comment: As you've certainly not shown any `copy` command, we can only assume that everything you're trying to do, is contained within `-f`/`--file=`. I would suggest therefore that the content of that file is an essential part of your question, and is therefore required to be included within it. Please use the [edit] facility, to update your question, such that potential responders have sufficient information upon which to base a focused response.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know postgress but i can hazard a solution. From the psql manual:

> psql returns 0 to the shell if it finished normally, 1 if a fatal
> error of its own occurs (e.g. out of memory, file not found), 2 if the
> connection to the server went bad and the session was not interactive,
> and 3 if an error occurred in a script and the variable ON_ERROR_STOP
> was set.

you can try:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem use double quote if there is space in filename.
cd "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v5\runtime"

rem psql command.
psql -h "Hostname" -p "5432" -U "user_name" -d "dbname" -c "\COPY (SELECT * FROM schema_name.table_name) TO "C:\ExportFromStaging\outputfile.csv" WITH (FORMAT CSV, HEADER TRUE, FORCE_QUOTE *, QUOTE '\"', ESCAPE '''',DELIMITER ';')

if %ERRORLEVEL% GEQ 1 (
   IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 1 set "result=psql fatal error."
   IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 2 set "result=psql connection to the server went bad."
   IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 3 set "result=psql error occurred in a script: '%ON_ERROR_STOP%'"
   echo psql error: [!date! !time!] !result!
   :: you can change "timestamp" with variable !date! !time!
   :: pseudocode:
   :: insert into error_log (error_message,error_time) values ("!result!","!date! !time!");
) else (
  IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 echo psql finished normally.
)
```